# Gerar valores randomicamente de um vetor sem repetições em C

Tags: c, array, random

Tenho o seguinte cenário, que é um vetor de perguntas que devem ser feitas ao usuário randomicamente.

O problema é que após eu inserir o primeiro valor do input o array é iterado logo em seguida listando todos os valores do vetor perguntas.
Dentro do laço while eu tenho um vetor para armazenar as respostas e outro para armazenar as perguntas ja feitas, dessa forma eu posso fazer uma comparação em seguida com o vetor de perguntas para que não sejam feitas perguntas repetidas.

A minha duvida é em relação ao que está acontecendo após eu passar o valor do input, porque será que ele fica em loop após o pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Abaixo está o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
  char perguntas[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c','d'};
  char respostas[4];
  char aux[4];

  int i =0;
  time_t t;
  srand((unsigned)time(&t));

  do{

      printf("%c\n", perguntas[rand()%4]);
      // scanf("%*c\n");
      scanf("%c\n",&respostas[i]);

      aux[i] = perguntas[rand()%4];

    }while( i < 4);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você sorteia um índice de pergunta (`printf("%c\n", perguntas[rand()%4]);`) mas lê uma resposta para o índice 0. Será que não deveria fazer `do { int k = rand()%4; printf("%c\n", perguntas[k]); scanf("%c\n", &respostas[k]); i++; } while( i < 4);`? Você pode inicializar o array respostas com um valor , por exemplo ' ', e testa-lo antes de guardar uma resposta, se já foi preenchido a pergunta é repetida.

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias situações que não estão certas nesse código:

- Cada vez que faz `perguntas[rand()%4]` gera um numero aleatório e por isso o número que gera e mostra para a pessoa não é o mesmo que guarda para comparar os que já sairam
- O `aux` não está a ser utilizado para perceber se uma pergunta já saiu
- **O `i` nunca é incrementado, logo está sempre com 0 virando um loop infinito**

Note que este ultimo ponto que mencionei responde diretamente à sua questão de ele ficar em loop.

Para além disso a lógica que tem não é boa. Melhor do que sortear e ver se já saiu é cada vez que sorteia, remove esse elemento da lista, evitando que possa sair no próximo sorteio. Isto acaba por simplificar no código e evitar situações em que gera montanhas de elementos até conseguir acertar num que ainda não tenha saido.

Exemplo da lógica que mencionei aplicada ao seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void remover_pergunta(char perguntas[], int sorteada, int qtd){
    int i;
    for (i = sorteada + 1; i < qtd; ++i){ //loop empurra a sorteada para o fim do array
        int temp = perguntas[i];
        perguntas[i] = perguntas[i - 1];
        perguntas[i -1 ] = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    char perguntas[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c','d'};
    char qtd_perguntas = sizeof(perguntas) / sizeof(char);
    char respostas[qtd_perguntas];
    int i = 0;
    srand (time(NULL));

    do{
        int pergunta_sorteada = rand() % qtd_perguntas; //sorteia pela posicao
        printf("%c\n", perguntas[pergunta_sorteada]); //mostra sorteada
        remover_pergunta(perguntas, pergunta_sorteada, qtd_perguntas); //"remove" sorteada
        qtd_perguntas--; //ajusta tamanho do array de perguntas
        scanf("%c\n",&respostas[i++]); //o incremento do i que estava em falta
    } while(qtd_perguntas > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/bj9WYm)

O pormenor a salientar no código é que o remover da pergunta, não remove de facto a pergunta a nível físico, ou seja em vez disso coloca a sorteada no fim, e diminui uma unidade no tamanho que estamos a considerar. Significa que em termos práticos é como se o array tivesse menos uma posição, apesar de o elemento ainda lá estar.